# Reflect-metadata errors after upgrade to angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

Angular 12 autoupdate removes `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` property from `tsconfig.json` and dev-version (`ng serve`) of app has error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: can't access property "name", d is undefined
```

at `vendor.js` file at this place:

```
... d=Reflect.getMetadata("design:type",e,r),v=!!d.name&&d.name.toLowerCase()===t.Array ...
```

Production build doesn't has this error

Including `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` at `tsconfig.json` eliminates this error

Installing and including polyfill `reflect-metadata` doesn't help

**Temporary solution**: include `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true`, but this is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's outside dependency error, and it strictly requires `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to roll back to the last usable version.

or a temporary fix would be to add these to your `package.json` and Change the Version of `@angular/Compiler-cli` to the exact same Version you have for `@angular/core`

"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8"

and for running ng don't use your global angular-cli, instead add it to your package.json and run it with npm.

```
"scripts": {
…
"build-my-app": "ng build --prod --aot --xyz"
},
```

and to run it:

```
npm run build-my-app
```